# Does the problem belong to NP class?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

So I am studying for my Algorithm theory exam and this is the problem i could not solve:

> Given numbers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ which are the sizes of $n$ files and disk capacity $D$. Determine if you can seperate these files into $3$ disks so that, in every disk sum of doesn't exceed $D$. Justify that this problem belongs to class NP

So i am thinking you can seperate only if:
$x_i < D$ and if $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n > 3\cdot D$
Are these the only rules?

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied or quoted material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody asked you to give conditions on when that happens. Also, your second condition is incorrect: if all $x_1,...,x_n$ are 0 then for any $D$ there is a solution.

What you are asked is to show this is in NP, hence, show a "prover-verifyer" solution:

The proof will be the following: for each $1\le i\le n$, the proof at index $i$, is $p_i$ and will be one of three numbers ($1,2,3$ for example) that will indicate in which disk we want to put the file $x_i$. Then, just check that for every one of the three disks, the sum of the $x$'s in it do not exceed $D$.

Its not hard to show why this algorithm is correct, so I will leave it for you to try on your own.